# Beginner Linux programming using xCode?

Tags: linux, xcode, project, openwrt

I am starting a project for a linux busy box environment. I haven't seen any information on it, but I need to basically interface with the GPIOs and various other parts of the system (this is for OpenWRT firmware).

Details are:
Linux OpenWrt 2.6.30.10 #24 Tue Apr 6 14:59:59 CEST 2010 mips GNU/Linux

So how do I start a project in xCode that can compile into this? Is that a lost cause? If so how do I start a project otherwise. I can do it on Linux but I've never started a project on that platform before.

Answer (score 1):

I think using xcode would make your project more complicated as you would have to use cross compilers for a foreign operating system.  Instead I would recommend using Eclipse CDT or Netbeans under Linux desktop; you'll still be using cross compilers but at least under the same O/S.

Answer (score 0):

xCode as in the Apple dev toolkit?

I can't be specific, but you'll need to install the linux x86 cross compiler for gcc, and then find out how to tell xCode to use it.

Comment: Okay, it sounds like I should just use my Linux box. Any recommendations on starting a project in Linux?